# LINQ: Find if one item in List appears in a string array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array and another object that has a list of objects, on of the properties is a string.

```
public string[] allowedroles;

foreach (var role in allowedroles)
{
   if (user.RolesList.Exists(r => r.Name == role))
   {
      authorize = true;
      break; // if one match that break out of loop
   }
}
```

Is there a way to perform with just a LINQ statement, without the foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var authorize = user.RolesList.Exists(r => allowedRoles.Contains(r.Name));
```

Or transform the list of roles into their names, and see whether that intersects with the allowed roles:

```
var authorize = user.RolesList.Select(r => r.Name).Intersect(allowedRoles).Any();
```

Note that you could use `Any` instead of `Exists`, which would stop it being specific to `List<T>`:

```
var authorize = user.RolesList.Any(r => allowedRoles.Contains(r.Name));
```

Also note that even though the `foreach` loop is no longer in the code, using LINQ won't make this code any *faster* - there's still a loop, it's just in the LINQ code rather than in your code. But hey, readability is still a big win :)